# Can't run API from other device on windows server(RDP) based GoLang

Tags: go, server, port, rdp

I have API GoLang based with port 1195, i want to run it from other device. I tried and it works on localhost to run the API with Postman.

But when i try to access the API from other device, it didn't work a.k.a Can't connect.

P.S:  My 8080 port is accessible for other device, but my 1195 is not accessible
Already allowed firewall for port 1195. Tried to change the port but still can't connect on other device

This is my config.ini:

```
{
    "app_name"       : "HELLOWORLD_API",
    "listening_port" : "1195",
    "host"           : "127.0.0.1",
    "port"           : "3306",
    "user"           : "root",
    "passwd"         : "",
    "dbname"        : "kube71"
}
```

I expect after I allowed the port 1195, I can connect to the API from other device.

Answer (score 0):

Try following config:

```
{ "app_name" : "HELLOWORLD_API", 
  "listening_port" : "1195", 
  "host" : "0.0.0.0", 
  "port" : "3306",
  ...
}
```

Basically, change 127.0.0.1 to 0.0.0.0.

To get more info on why this is the case, have a look at https://superuser.com/questions/949428/whats-the-difference-between-127-0-0-1-and-0-0-0-0

Putting simply, 0.0.0.0 meaning it will be available to connect from all networks, not only from local

Comment: tried to change it and still can't connect, could it be the main.exe is not windows service?
bcs my 8080 is apache and 3306 mysql are registered on windows service.

Comment: No, it;s not because 'it is not a service'. have you checked your firewall? your networking settings etc?

Comment: i allowed 1195, i setted it as i set my 8080 (apache)

Comment: how do you use that config in your code? can you show how you create server listener?

Comment: func main() {
 fileConfig := flag.String("f", "e_channel.ini", "config file")
 flag.Parse()
 config, err := config_db.LoadConfig(*fileConfig)
 if err != nil {
  fmt.Println(err.Error())
 }

 db := config_db.Connectdb(config)
 inDB := &controller.DB{DBE: db}
 r := gin.Default()

fmt.Println("Listening at Port " + config.ListeningPort)
 r.Run(":" + config.ListeningPort)
}

Comment: sorry for the mess, first time using stackoverflow hehe

Comment: Don't worry, everyone started some day :) Feel free to edit your question and put that code there :)

Comment: r.Run(":" + config.ListeningPort)  - so it seems you don't use the config.host setting at all. and I assume it will be 127.0.0.1 by default not 0.0.0.0 and that will be an issue.

Comment: just try r.Run(config.Host + ":" + config.ListeningPort)

Comment: the result is Listening and Serving HTTP on 0.0.0.0 : 1195

again i tried to connect from other device, i recheck the firewall, but still none.